# how to list full paths of folders inside a directory in linux?

Tags: linux, shell, ubuntu, command-line, fedora

I have a folder `/home/Documents/myFolder` and inside this folder there are lots other folders. I want to have a file `list.txt` which contains all the paths of the folders. I want the text file content like this:

```
 /home/Documents/myFolder/1234
 /home/Documents/myFolder/asd2
 /home/Documents/myFolder/asdawgf
 /home/Documents/myFolder/dawt
 .
 .
 .
```

I tried this one but it was not what I  want `ls >  /home/Documents/myFolde/list.txt`
it just prints the folder names. I want the full paths.

Comment: `ls -d "$PWD"/* > listOfFiles.list`

Answer (score 1):

Use `find` listing all directories (`-type d`) and then sed the output to get the full path correct:

```
find . -type d | sed -n 's:^\./:/home/Documents/myFolder/:'p > /home/Documents/myFolder/list.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use find:

```
find . > /home/Documents/myFolde/list.txt
```

Comment: no, it also list sub folders of the folders

Comment: so, u mean only directories, not files, is that so?

Comment: yeah this works `ls -rt -d -1 $PWD/* > /home/Documents/myFolde/list.txt`